# Increase Header size Rotativa

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, rotativa

I'm Using Rotativa to convert HTML as PDF, And I need to add Header on each page. it is showing if the header HTML size is small but when I increase the HTML height top of HTML cant visible n there is no top margin showing. is there any option to increase header size on rotativa

Here are My custom Switches for add header and footer

```
  string customSwitches = $"--header-html  \"{header}\" " +
               "--header-spacing \"0\" " +
               $"--footer-html \"{footer}\" " +
               "--footer-spacing \"-1\" " +
               "--footer-font-size \"10\" " +
               "--header-font-size \"10\" " +
               "--footer-font-name \"Segoe UI\" ";
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it in your controller,

```
var actionResult = new ActionAsPdf("*action_name*",new {param1 = value})
{
    PageMargins = new Margins(2, 2, 0, 2),
    PageWidth = 210,
    PageHeight = 297
};
```

You may convert it and write it to local in the background:

```
var byteArray = actionResult.BuildPdf(ControllerContext);

FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filePath);
file.Directory?.Create();
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(file.FullName, byteArray);
```

Comment: so should I remove custom switches? if removed, how can I set header and footer for all pages